# sed or grep command to extract all lines that match a particular date and time range

Tags: linux, grep, sed

```
2022-09-08T08:55:10+02:00             
2022-09-08T19:55:16+02:00            200     200     76  0GET /v1/heartbeat/tcanalytics HTTP/1.1     
2022-09-08T23:55:17+02:00             200     200    POST /v1/accountmanagement             
2022-09-10T20:55:17+02:00        200     200     76  0GET /v1/heartbeat/tcanalytics HTTP/1.1       
2022-09-08T21:55:10+02:00              0.000   -       -      172 0GET /v1/heartbeat/tcanalytics H   
2022-09-10T21:55:17+02:00             200     200     1403643      POST /v1/accountmanagement        
2022-09-10T22:55:17+02:00
```

My file looks something like this . What we need to get from this file is everything on 2022-09-08 and particular time rage from 8 to 10 am.  I tried this

`'sed -n '/2022-09-08T08:00:26+02:00/,/2022-09-08T11:00:26+02:00/p' logfile`

but it did not work. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Side note: it's somewhat weird the timestamps in the logfile are not in sequence.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly means "it did not work"? Show the error message or the wrong output and the expected output. It would be good to provide example input that contains matching lines from different hours.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your command. The single quote before `sed` is wrong. (Or another quote would be required after it to unnecessarily quote the word `sed`.)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does not know about time and date, so giving it a time-range will not work. `dateutils` knows about dates, in particular `dategrep` would work well in this instance, e.g.:

```
dategrep '>=2022-09-08T08:00:26+02:00 && <=2022-09-08T11:00:26+02:00' < infile
```

Output:

```
2022-09-08T08:55:10+02:00
```

Or with a wider range:

```
dategrep '>=2022-09-08T08:00:26+02:00 && <=2022-09-08T23:00:26+02:00' < infile
```

Output:

```
2022-09-08T08:55:10+02:00
2022-09-08T19:55:16+02:00        200     200     76  0GET /v1/heartbeat/tcanalytics HTTP/1.1
2022-09-08T21:55:10+02:00                        0.000   -       -      172 0GET /v1/heartbeat/tcanalytics H
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution assumes that the time range starts and ends on a full hour.

To get a time range from `2022-09-08T08:00:00` to `2022-09-08T10:59:59`, you can use

```
grep '^2022-09-08T08:
^2022-09-08T09:
^2022-09-08T10:' logfile
```

For bigger time ranges, listing all dates and hours would get impractical.

The example input from the question

```
2022-09-08T08:55:10+02:00
2022-09-08T19:55:16+02:00            200     200     76  0GET /v1/heartbeat/tcanalytics HTTP/1.1
2022-09-08T23:55:17+02:00             200     200    POST /v1/accountmanagement 
2022-09-10T20:55:17+02:00        200     200     76  0GET /v1/heartbeat/tcanalytics HTTP/1.1
2022-09-08T21:55:10+02:00              0.000   -       -      172 0GET /v1/heartbeat/tcanalytics H
2022-09-10T21:55:17+02:00             200     200     1403643      POST /v1/accountmanagement
2022-09-10T22:55:17+02:00
```

results in a single output line

```
2022-09-08T08:55:10+02:00
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` operates on strings, it does not understand the concept of dates. For your `/2022-09-08T08:00:26+02:00/,/2022-09-08T11:00:26+02:00/p` to work, the exact strings `2022-09-08T08:00:26+02:00` and `2022-09-08T11:00:26+02:00` have to be in the file.

We can inject them; then we need to sort by timestamps; and *then* your `sed` should work.

Fortunately the timestamps in your `logfile` are in a format that can easily be sorted with `LC_ALL=C sort -k 1,1`, if only all the timestamps end with `+02:00`.

```
start='2022-09-08T08:00:26+02:00'
end='2022-09-08T11:00:26+02:00'

printf '%s\n%s\n' "$start" "$end" \
| LC_ALL=C sort -k 1,1 - logfile \
| sed -n "/$start/,/$end/p"
```

Notes:

- The output will include the `$start` line we injected and all lines from `logfile` with this exact timestamp (not necessarily in this order).
- The output will include exactly one line with the `$end` timestamp. It may be the `$end` line we injected, or it may be a line from `logfile` with this exact timestamp. Other lines with this exact timestamp won't be printed.
- If `logfile` is large, `sort` will have to do lot of work. This can be avoided if timestamps in the file are already sorted; use `sort -m` if they are. Usually timestamps in a log are sorted, but *in your example they are not*.
- `printf` will simply print what `$start` and `$end` expand to. In `sed` the expanded variables will be interpreted at least as regular expressions, but in general as *code*. Timestamps in question contain no characters that would break the `sed` code or be special in regex, so *in this case* it should be safe.
- I think [`dategrep` from this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1742683/432690) is probably the right tool. Use it if you can. My answer is supposed to be a more portable (stub of a) solution.